# WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start error with Selenium ChromeDriver and Chromium through Java

Tags: java, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I was trying to achieve a page login through selenium-java libraries. Driver that I am using is Chromium (open source version of chrome). This implementation is working fine in Windows environment, but when I ran this implementation through Jenkins(Linux box) Driver is failing to start. I am expecting to see no issues while instantiation of ChromeDriver and it should start without any issues.

Here are the details of Linux environment.

- **Browser and driver:** Chromium 73.0.3683.86 Fedora Project
- **Driver path in linux box**: /usr/bin/chromium-browser.sh
- **Java Version**: 1.8.0_131
- **Selenium version used**: 3.14.0 and tried with latest 3.141.59 as well
- **OS** : Linux

I ensured and verified that the file has full permissions to execute from Jenkins user.

**Code which I am trying**

```
        String OS = System.getProperty("os.name", "generic").toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        if (OS.indexOf("win") >= 0) {
            filePath = new File(properties.getChromeDriverPath()).getAbsolutePath();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", filePath);
        } else if (OS.indexOf("nux") >= 0) {
            File chromiumDriver = new File("/usr/bin/chromium-browser");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromiumDriver.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        options.setHeadless(true);
        WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**Error logs.**

```
com.src.test.services.integration.test.AuthServicesTest > testAuthentication STANDARD_ERROR
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
    Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
    System info: host: 'xyzJenkinsHost.test.corp', ip: '172.20.3.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
    Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:193)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:179)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)

com.src.test.services.integration.test.AuthServicesTest > testAuthentication STANDARD_ERROR
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:19154/status] to be available after 20002 ms
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:188)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
        ... 22 more
```

Comment: Do you get the correct path on **chromiumDriver.getAbsolutePath()**

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan yes, tried with console output and its accurate. File is exists and it's executable too

Comment: Did you find any solution? On my local system the code works fine, but I get error when deployed on server.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'xyzJenkinsHost.test.corp', ip: '172.20.3.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowsing Session** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_131** which is pretty **ancient**.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u6131* and *Selenium Client v3.141.59*.

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [JDK 8u212](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to [ChromeDriver v76.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=76.0.3809.25/) level.
- Upgrade *Chrome* to *Chrome v76.0* level.

Comment: Thank you so much the answer. Due to some reasons I can't upgrade existing Linux environment. Can I make my script working by downgrading the Selenium version to some older versions?

Comment: @RajeshKumar Reverse engineering would ba a tougher call. Upgrade _JDK_ atleast.

Comment: the issue has nothing to do with Java compatibility

Answer (score 0):

```
File chromiumDriver = new File("/usr/bin/chromium-browser");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromiumDriver.getAbsolutePath());
```

You are setting the `webdriver.chrome.driver` system property to the location of `chromium-browser`.  Instead, you must set the property to point to where the `chromdriver` executable is located (which you should have downloaded somewhere).